# verifying winner in tictactoe game

Tags: java, refactoring

I have written some code for the Tic Tac Toe game:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        String line = null;
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                line = bd[0] + bd[1] + bd[2];
                break;
            case 1:
                line = bd[3] + bd[4] + bd[5];
                break;
            case 2:
                line = bd[6] + bd[7] + bd[8];
                break;
            case 3:
                line = bd[0] + bd[3] + bd[6];
                break;
            case 4:
                line = bd[1] + bd[4] + bd[7];
                break;
            case 5:
                line = bd[2] + bd[5] + bd[8];
                break;
            case 6:
                line = bd[0] + bd[4] + bd[8];
                break;
            case 7:
                line = bd[2] + bd[4] + bd[6];
                break;
        }
        if (line.equals("XXX")) {
            return "X";
        } else if (line.equals("OOO")) {
            return "O";
        }
    }
```

The line in the switch statement is just checking if any of the eight lines in tic tac toe
has the same character. This seems to be a lot of code for this purpose. Could there be
an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace if-statements with Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71736076/replace-if-statements-with-loops)

Answer (score 1):

You could define once the 8 lines indexes, then use it to check for a winner

```
static int[][] lines = new int[][]{
        {0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, // rows
        {0, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, // cols
        {0, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 6}             // diags
};

static String check(String[] bd) {
    for (int[] line : lines) {
        StringBuilder lineSymbols = new StringBuilder();
        for (int idx : line) {
            lineSymbols.append(bd[idx]);
        }

        if (lineSymbols.toString().equals("XXX")) {
            return "X";
        } else if (lineSymbols.toString().equals("OOO")) {
            return "O";
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

Know that now when enhanced switch it could look like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    String line = switch (i) {
        case 0 -> bd[0] + bd[1] + bd[2];
        case 1 -> bd[3] + bd[4] + bd[5];
        case 2 -> bd[6] + bd[7] + bd[8];
        case 3 -> bd[0] + bd[3] + bd[6];
        case 4 -> bd[1] + bd[4] + bd[7];
        case 5 -> bd[2] + bd[5] + bd[8];
        case 6 -> bd[0] + bd[4] + bd[8];
        case 7 -> bd[2] + bd[4] + bd[6];
        default -> null;
    };
    if (line.equals("XXX")) {
        return "X";
    } else if (line.equals("OOO")) {
        return "O";
    }
}
```